# Как увеличить расход ресурсов компьютера

Tags: производительность, python-3.8

У меня есть python скрипт, он потребляет всего 10% мощности процессора. Можно ли как-то дать возможность использовать всю мощность, для прироста скорости? Можно ли как-то перенести нагрузку на видеокарту?

Comment: Многопоточность и многопроцессность. Для видеокарты нужно изучать cuda и opencl

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/679679/how-to-increase-pythons-cpu-usage